# Why is PHP not recompiling with nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, centos7, recompile

PHP is not recompiling properly.

I have PHP 7.2 installed on Nginx using php-fpm on Centos 7. I am recompiling php with more options using ./configure, make clean, make, make test and make install.

> Everything works well and no errors are thrown, except the updated php
>   compile is not being reflected on the phpinfo(); table. If you see the
>   **"Build Date"** it is not changing. The **"Configure Command"** is also not updating after recompiling.

Why could php not be recompiling and the **"Build Date"** not updating, and the **"Configure Command"** also not reflecting my changes?

I have restarted nginx, restarted php-fpm, and still no change. I can edit the php.ini file without problems as well and they do update, but the php itself is not updating after I recompile and add more options (--with-openssl). I even restarted the server. PHP files are served fine.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I was genuinely stuck with this problem for several hours, seems unfair to have the question downvoted a few minutes after I posted. It would have definitely helped me and therefore it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

> **I just figured it out** after about half a day.

The reason the new php recompile was not being recognized was because I needed to manually copy the new updated php-fpm program to the /usr/local/bin directory, like this:

```
cp sapi/fpm/php-fpm /usr/local/bin
```

And that fixed it. So basically php WAS being recompiled correctly, but that was not seen by the system because php-fpm was not manually copied to the directory nginx uses to pull php-fpm from. The file must be overwritten while php-fpm is turned off.

> **Bonus Tip**

This is my command to reload php, php-fpm and nginx after recompiling:

```
# gracefully stop the php-fpm process
pkill -15 php-fpm

# copy the new recompiled php-fpm to the executable directory
cp -f sapi/fpm/php-fpm /usr/local/bin

# start php-fpm
/usr/local/bin/php-fpm

# signal nginx to reload
nginx -s reload
```

All in one line:

```
pkill -15 php-fpm && cp -f sapi/fpm/php-fpm /usr/local/bin && /usr/local/bin/php-fpm && nginx -s reload
```